# Command to print content before a symbol (last character in a line)

Tags: text-processing, filenames

Let's consider I have 3 files:

```
abc_def_12345.zip
abc_123.zip
abc_def_ghi_3432.zip
```

I want to print only the characters before the last underscore(_)

The expected output is:

```
abc_def
abc
abc_def_ghi
```

Comment: Do you want to do it per-file? Or on a list of files at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed, you could try

```
sed -E 's/(.*)_.*/\1/'
```

example, copy paste this into a command prompt

```
% cat << EOF | sed -E 's/(.*)_.*/\1/'
abc_def_12345.zip
abc_123.zip
abc_def_ghi_3432.zip
EOF
```

output

```
abc_def
abc
abc_def_ghi
```

note, this command leaves `sed`'s automatic printing of the pattern space in place, which means any other lines which don't match the patten (i.e. don't contain any `_`'s, will be part of the output. If you don't want these, you could use

```
sed -n -E 's/(.*)_.*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash with parameter expansion:

```
$ foo="abc_def_ghi_3432.zip"; echo "${foo%_*}"
$ abc_def_ghi
```